# Find $T(2)$ in recurrence relation $T(n)=2(T(\sqrt{n}))^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Here, if we have recurrence relation $T(n)=2(T(\sqrt{n}))^2$, where $T(1)=4$, how we can get $T(2)$ please? We substitute the value of 2 in the equation etc? The answer I have says it's 4? We can not get to $T(1) $ from $T(2)$ as $T(\sqrt{n})$ would be a fraction. What do you think please?

**Answer**: $T(2) = 4$, so any hint here please?

Comment: $4=T(1)=2(T(\sqrt{1}))^2=2\cdot 4^2$, a contradiction.

Comment: @DietrichBurde. Thank you. It's given in the question that $T(1) = 4$. This is why I am asking. I think there might be something wrong in the question itself. Probably, the question meant to say $T(2) = 4$?

Comment: You can put the statement: "For any $T$ that satisfies this, we must have $T=2021$" and it shall be true by vacuity

Comment: Weird question. First of all this is not a normal recurrence equation. It formally only makes sense for special inputs (when $n$ is a square). Though these kinds of recurrence relations are often found when analyzing algorithms to find the complexity and when solving them we only care about the large $n$ behavior so it doesn't make much sense to me to ask about $T(2)$ given $T(1)$. You could formally "solve it" (for $n$'s on the form $2^{2^k}$) to get something like $T(n) = (n/2) T(2)^{\log_2(n)}$ and plug in $n=1$ and $n=2$, but as pointed out above it doesn't make sense unless $T(1) = 1/2$.

Comment: @Winther. Thank you. I see that $T(n)$ above is the recurrence equation solution that you got, but for $T(2)$ how you define it then please?

Comment: $T(2)$ does not follow from $T(1)$. It is a free constant in that solution (the initial condition) from which the 'solution' for other $n$'s follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
T(n) = 2(T(\sqrt{n}))^2\Rightarrow \log_2(T(n))=1+2\log_2(T(\sqrt{n}))
$$

$$
t(\cdot) \equiv \log_2(T(\cdot))\Rightarrow t(n) = 1 +2t(\sqrt{n})
$$

$$
t\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right)= 1 + 2t\left(2^{\log_2 \sqrt{n}}\right)
$$

now with $\mathcal{T}(\cdot) = t\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right), \ z = \log_2 n$ we follow with

$$
\mathcal{T}(z) = 1 + 2\mathcal{T}\left(\frac z2\right)
$$

with solution

$$
\mathcal{T}(z) =z-1 + \frac z2 c_1
$$

going backwards with $z = \log_2 n$ we get $t(n) = \log_2 n(1+\frac{c_1}{2})-1$ and finally

$$
T(n) = 2^{\log_2 n(1+\frac{c_1}{2})-1}
$$

Comment: Thank you. One question please about $
t(\cdot) \equiv \log_2(T(\cdot))\Rightarrow t(n) = 1 +2t(\sqrt{n})
$, how you derive it? What topic in math discusses how to represent such forms please?